# Burninate code-example and code-examples tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, meta-tags

I just stumbled across the [code-example](/questions/tagged/code-example) (12 Questions) and [code-examples](/questions/tagged/code-examples) (111 questions) tag.

They seem like a meta-tags.

Should they be burninated or is it useful to keep them and clean them up somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## BURN THEM!

### BURM THEM ALL!!

[image]

All of those types of questions seem like [gimme-codez](/questions/tagged/gimme-codez)...
And if they are not, then they should remove the burnt tag and reorganize how their question is asked.