# I don't feel this edit of my question is a major improvement; am I right and should I re-edit it?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

The [edit (#4)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15205280/revisions) to my question deletes all of the namespaces and adds 2 tags.

My question is two-fold:

Should the namespaces not be kept to keep the code SSCCE? At minimum I think the ObjectModel namespace should be kept, but I don't like letting people make assumptions about what needs to be included (though a good IDE would tell you a namespace is missing, I'd rather it just be ready to fly).

What is the purpose of the [example](/questions/tagged/example) tag? It seems...pointless. I've only found [Burninate code-example and code-examples tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125600/201013) when doing a search for this on meta, so not sure if [example](/questions/tagged/example) is evil or not.

Only the [data-binding](/questions/tagged/data-binding) tag seems to be important. **Would I be correct in undoing most of the edit except for that tag, or has the post been improved (and I should leave it alone)?**

Comment: I agree. Rollbacked.

Comment: Is the data-binding tag worth having, @Doorknob?

Comment: If you think so, then edit it in. It really isn't too major to worry about though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editors's intent was good. It's a long question (might even have attracted attention by being tagged with the automatic "excessively long" flag). Much of the edit was ok:

- Most of the auto-generated usings are unnecessary.
- The auto-generated class comment is just noise.
- The data-binding tag is useful.

As you note, though, it's not a SSCCE any more, without any usings.

If it were me, I'd leave the edit alone, but add back in the required usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel; //For ObservableCollection<T>
using System.Windows;
```

And remove the silly [example] tag.

No hue and cry if you just rollback the whole thing, though.

Comment: Yea, I shed no tear for the auto-comment. This seems to be the correct approach and in line with what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: What's the "excessively long" flag? I've had *much* longer questions...

Comment: @Hydronium: In addition to flags that users can raise, Stack Exchange sites generate rule-based flags based on various criteria. Too long (more than a page or so of text?), duplicate answer (among the user's own answers - catches spam), too many comments (is there a flame war going on?), rollback war, etc. They're only visible to 10k+ users, and I'll bet there are others visible only to moderators. They're only intermittently useful (too many comments rarely so, rollback war very often).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Hydronium: oh, and in case I gave the impression, I don't know if your post was so flagged, and even if it was, don't worry about it. The flag is meant, I think, for questions starting with *My code is broken!*, followed by 5K lines of code.